# Trying to remove the date from Panda's series using df.dt.time but getting an object back

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to remove the date from a series in the `datetime64` format so that I can plot data starting from 8 am in one plot.

I tried this:

```
df['time_no_date']= df['time'].dt.time
```

However, now I'm unable to plot `df['time_no_date']` because its an **object** and not a **datetime**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot directly from  `df['time']`. Set a start and end datetime using code along the lines of (but with your date and time):

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2023-02-27 08:00:00')
end = pd.to_datetime('2023-02-27 23:00:00')
```

then select the rows from the DF between the two values for a new DF:

```
df2 = df.loc[(df['time'] > start) & (df['time'] <= end)]
```

and then use df2 for plotting with df2['time'] for one axis